# Not too sure about replace() function on Python - why isn't dog being replaced with cat?

Tags: python

```
a = 'dog'

a.replace('dog', 'cat')

print (a)
```

Really basic question, the function seems to be fairly straightforward but it just isn't replacing in this instance for some reason - is it because replace doesn't inherently change "a"?

Comment: `new_a = a.replace('dog', 'cat')` you need to assign it to a new variable or reassign it to the variable `a`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable data types in Python which means that its value cannot be updated. Variables can point at whatever they want.

`str.replace()` creates a copy of string with replacements applied. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Need to assign a new variable for the replacement.

```
a = 'dog'
b = a.replace('dog', 'cat')
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. It won’t modify a.

Replace function will return a replaced string.

So, if you like to replace the text in a. Use the below code.

a = 'dog'
a = a.replace('dog', 'cat')
print (a)